flutter pub upgrade is not upgrading my dependencies
AFter I load a flutter project from GitHub and run flutter get pub I am getting this in the terminal window:
 PS C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence> flutter pub get
Flutter assets will be downloaded from
https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this     
source!
Resolving dependencies... (1.1s)
Note: web is pinned to version 0.4.2 by flutter_test from the flutter SDK.
See https://dart.dev/go/sdk-version-pinning for details.    


Because every version of flutter_test from sdk depends on   
  web 0.4.2 and deal_diligence depends on web ^0.5.0,       
  flutter_test from sdk is forbidden.
So, because deal_diligence depends on flutter_test from     
  sdk, version solving failed.

I have tried several of the solutions I found here in stackoverflow.com but nothing works.
I have tried flutter pub upgrade but I get the same error.
This is the output of flutter doctor:
PS C:\deal_diligence\deal_diligence> flutter doctor -v
Flutter assets will be downloaded from
https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this     
source!
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.8, on Microsoft Windows
    [Version 10.0.22631.3810], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.16.8 on channel stable at
      c:\src\flutter\flutter
    • Upstream repository
      https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 67457e669f (6 months ago),
      2024-01-16 16:22:29 -0800
    • Engine revision 6e2ea58a5c
    • Dart version 3.2.5
    • DevTools version 2.28.5
    • Pub download mirror https://pub.flutter-io.cn
    • Flutter download mirror https://storage.flutter-io.cn

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version
    10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android
    SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at
      C:\Users\nkane\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android      
      Studio1\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build       
      17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program
      Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio     
    Community 2022 17.8.5)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual    
      Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.8.34511.84    
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android    
      Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter    
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart       
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build       
      11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] Android Studio (version 2023.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android    
      Studio1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter    
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart       
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build       
      17.0.7+0-b2043.56-10550314)

[√] VS Code (version 1.91.0)
    • VS Code at
      C:\Users\nkane\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS    
      Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.92.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    •        
      Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3810]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google 
      Chrome 126.0.6478.127
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript •        
      Microsoft Edge 126.0.2592.87

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

Here are the dependencies in the pubspec.yaml file:
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_riverpod: ^2.4.3
  # firebase_auth: ^4.10.1
  firebase_auth: ^4.19.5
  # cloud_firestore: ^4.9.3
  cloud_firestore: ^4.17.3
  # firebase_core: ^2.17.0
  firebase_core: ^2.31.0
  firebase_core_web: ^2.17.0
  modal_progress_hud_nsn: ^0.5.1
  mask_text_input_formatter: ^2.5.0
  uuid: ^4.1.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.14
  intl: ^0.19.0
  webview_flutter: ^4.4.1
  web: ^0.4.2
  table_calendar: ^3.0.9
  persistent_bottom_nav_bar_v2: ^5.2.3
  # firebase_messaging: ^14.7.4
  firebase_messaging: ^14.9.2
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.2
  google_fonts: ^6.2.0
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.1.0
  http: ^1.1.0
  purchases_flutter: ^6.5.1
  googleapis: ^13.1.0
  googleapis_auth: ^1.4.1
  add_2_calendar: ^3.0.1
  mailer: ^6.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^6.2.1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^4.0.0
  change_app_package_name: ^1.1.0

What can I do to get these dependencies to register?
Thanks

Have you tried upgrading your Flutter Sdk too?

Thank you @belinda.g.freitas, that was the fix.

you're welcome.
